# pouchdb-authentication how do I set roles for a new user

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I want to set roles for a new user.

I tried updating roles array in metadata during signup but I get an error.  If I remove the roles metadata new user is created just fine.

```js
db.signUp(userId, 'pass', {
    metadata: {
      email: 'robi434n@boywonder.com',
      birthday: '1932-03-27T00:00:00.000Z',
      likes: ['acrobatics', 'short pants', 'sidekickin\'']
      roles: ['basic']
    }
  }, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      if (err.name === 'conflict') {
        console.log('batman" already exists, choose another username')
        // "batman" already exists, choose another username
      } else if (err.name === 'forbidden') {
        console.log('invalid username')
        // invalid username
      } else {
        console.log('sign up error')
        // HTTP error, cosmic rays, etc.
      }
    } else {
      console.log('user signed up')
     // login()
    }
  })
```

So I figured it out first modify the pouchdb-authentication index.js code to accept roles.

```
var signUp = pouchdbUtils.toPromise(function (username, password,roles, opts, callback) {
  var db = this;
  if (typeof callback === 'undefined') {
    callback = typeof opts === 'undefined' ? (typeof password === 'undefined' ?
      username : password) : opts;
    opts = {};
  }
  if (['http', 'https'].indexOf(db.type()) === -1) {
    return callback(new AuthError('This plugin only works for the http/https adapter. ' +
      'So you should use new PouchDB("http://mysi3te.org:5984/mydb") instead.'));
  } else if (!username) {
    return callback(new AuthError('You must provide a username'));
  } else if (!password) {
    return callback(new AuthError('You must provide a password'));
  }

  var userId = 'org.couchdb.user:' + username;
  var user = {
    name: username,
    password: password,
    roles: roles,
    type: 'user',
    _id: userId,
  };

  updateUser(db, user, opts, callback);
});
```

Then you can send the roles in the sign up. I'm sending basic below

```
   signUp()
function signUp () {
  db.signUp(userId, 'pass', ['basic'], {
    metadata: {
      email: 'robi434n@boywonder.com',
      birthday: '1932-03-27T00:00:00.000Z',
      likes: ['acrobatics', 'short pants', 'sidekickin\'']
    }
  }, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      if (err.name === 'conflict') {
        console.log('batman" already exists, choose another username')
        // "batman" already exists, choose another username
      } else if (err.name === 'forbidden') {
        console.log('invalid username', err)
        // invalid username
      } else {
        console.log('sign up error', err)
        // HTTP error, cosmic rays, etc.
      }
    } else {
      console.log('user signed up', err)
      login()
    }
  })
}
```

now you have to go to couchdb _user database _design/_auth document modify

```
else if (newDoc.roles.length > 0 ) {\n
```

set this to

```
else if (newDoc.roles.length > 0 && newDoc.roles[0] !== 'basic' ) {\n
```

Now you will have basic in your session and can add more roles my adjusting the code a bit. This allows me to set member role permissions easily to limit access to other databases. Or a simpler solution i found and tested is to  add a new design doc to your database with the following code. It will only allow users that are logged in to access your database

```
{
  "_id": "_design/usersOnly",
  "_rev": "17-6fb7e6c0ccfca8b2e56738ad63e26107",
  "language": "javascript",
  "validate_doc_update": "\n  function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx){   \n // check if user is logged in \n  if(!userCtx.name){ throw({forbidden : 'No way.. login man!'});}   \n //reqired fields to update \n  function require(field){   var message = field + ' is required';  if(!newDoc[field]){  throw({'forbidden':message})  }}   require('name');                                         }"
}
```

Comment: If you aren't preventing length>1 then I think you should be restricting the list of user added roles to both to prevent `roles = ["basic","delegatedadminrole"]` from biting you later and to allow the free user roles in any order.

Comment: I don't think you need to change pouchdb-authentication and updated my answer..

Comment: I'll def add the length > 1. Thanks a bunch for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

The [validate function design documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions) uses the _users design document as the primary example:

> Example: The _design/_auth ddoc from _users database uses a validation function to ensure that documents contain some required fields and are only modified by a user with the _admin role:

```
        ...
        } else if (newDoc.roles.length > 0) {
            throw({forbidden: 'Only _admin may set roles'});
        }
        ...
```

In fauxton (for example) you can login as the couchdb admin user and go to _users database and change the design (at your own peril), for example:

```
        } else if (newDoc.roles.length > 0 && !("basic" === newRoles[0] && newDoc.roles.length === 1)) {
            throw({forbidden: 'Only _admin may set roles'});
        }
```

saving it as you would any other document. (I say peril, since subtle accidents in this design document can potentially allow unauthorized users to drastically raise their permissions.)

With such a change, new users are allowed to be created with the basic role by couchdb, so your client code works if it sets roles correctly. In pouchdb-authenticate this seems to be with [opt.roles](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/blob/19f547b7bde97801a889e62ba93667937fc32af5/src/users.js#L37) and not opt.metadata.roles, i.e.:

```
db.signUp(userId, 'pass', {
    metadata: {
      email: 'robi434n@boywonder.com',
      birthday: '1932-03-27T00:00:00.000Z',
      likes: ['acrobatics', 'short pants', 'sidekickin\'']
    },
    roles: ['basic'] }, ... )
```

Comment: Thanks for your post helped a lot. I'll update with how I ended up doing it